# Why loading fails and consequently promises don't get resolved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

This snippet is part of a bigger directive:

```
        var imageArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.abbreviations.length; i++) {
          imageArray[i] = new Image();
          imageArray[i].src = $scope.abbreviations[i].imgPath;
         };
        console.log(imageArray);

        function preLoad() {

            var promises = [];

            function loadImage(src) {
                return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.src = src;
                    image.onload = function () {
                        resolve(image);
                        console.log('onload:', src);
                    };
                    image.onerror = function (e) {
                        reject(e);
                        console.log('onerror:', e);
                    };
                })
            }
            imageArray.forEach(function (src) {
                console.log('forEach:', src);
                promises.push(loadImage(src));
            });

            return $q.all(promises).then(function (results) {
                console.log('Promises resolved with', results);
                $scope.results = results;
            });
        }
        preLoad().then(function () {
            console.log('Ready for next activity...');
        });
```

and this screenshot shows the logs in my console:

[image]

Question: why the loading function fails and, as a consequence, the promises don't get resolved?

Comment: Looks like the logs gives you clues. It is because your image loads fails resuting in error event which reject the promise and you are only chaining through `then` block of promise returned by q.all, chain a catch block and see. q.all promise will be resolved _only_ if all the underlying promises are resolved.

Comment: @PSL cheers I can see that. So why loading fails? thanks

Comment: That should be your question right? then, it has nothing to do with promises --> `why the load functions fails and, as a consequence, the promises don't get resolved?`.

Comment: @PSL I've update the question

Comment: Your image url might be wrong. DId you add that image tag manually in an html page and test ? Also check the network cconsole for any 404 or any other load errors on the resource. Also try assigning `image.src = src;` after setting the handlers (onload, onerror) on the image.

Comment: @PSL  Yes, the images are retrieved successfully (200). I can see the images in my view. I'll try adding the catch block.

Comment: Please note, you should be setting the src property *after* you bind the onload event, otherwise the load event may not fire in some browsers if the image is cached.

Comment: @KevinB and PSL thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
imageArray.forEach(function(src) {
   ...
}
```

You pass into a `forEach` callback an element of `imageArray` - but that's *already* an Image object. That's why when you assign it into a new Image's src, loading fails.

The easiest solution would be skipping that loop in the beginning of your code, and augment `forEach` callback so that it works with the original object. In fact, it's cleaner to use `.map` with returning the result:

```
promises = $scope.abbreviations.map(function(imgObj) {
   return loadImage(imgObj.imgPath);
});
```

Comment: There's a useful rule of thumb - if you add an element to some array on each call of `forEach` callback, consider using `map` instead. That's exactly what I've done there. )

Comment: That looks neater and it works. Learnt two things, thanks a lot.